# Collision strength of Java's Arrays.hashCode

Tags: java, arrays, hash

How strong is the hashing mechanism that is used in the `Arrays.hashCode` methods against collision? What is the possibility of two different arrays (of, say, `double`) to have an exact hash value calculated with these methods?

Comment: "similar" hash value? Why should that matter? Do you actually care about "similar" values or do you want to know about *real* collisions?

Comment: Bear in mind that *any* 32 bit hashing mechanism is going to be considered "weak", as if you take 4.3 billion (or so) objects and hash them (not that many in the grand scheme of things), you're guaranteed to get at least one collision. They're generally designed primarily to be fast and, secondly to the above, avoid collisions *most* of the time to improve efficiency in "HashX" collection type scenarios.

Comment: In general, IIRC, hash collision chance is around 50% for a given double. Simply based on its bit size compared to `int`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer that was a mistake. I meant 'exact'. I corrected the question. Thanks for the keen observation.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov hashcode collision for any 2 arbitrary objects is `1/2³²`, based on the fact that a hashcode is `int` (provided no pathological implementation of `hashCode()`). Bit size has little to do with it, and you'd need a lot of existing doubles for the collision chance to become `50%`.

Comment: @Kayaman, ah, yes, true. I blanked out for some reason. Though I do feel like I had something going for my case, since `double` hash code is stable and depends on its value. What I was getting at is since `double` size is 64 bit, there is always one other double value whos hash code is identical to a given value.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: in fact there are (almost) 2^32 different double values for each possible hash value. Since the hash code for `Double` (and thus `double`) is simply defined as the XOR of the upper half with the lower half it's pretty easy to construct all of those `double` values for a given. The reason that you can't quite produce 2^32 values for each is that all possible bit patterns representing `NaN` are collapsed to a single canonical one for the purpose of hash code calculation.

Comment: @Kayaman Whereas the chance of two arbitrary objects having the same hash code is 1/(2^32), the chance of collision in a collection of objects is 50% with only about 75,000 objects. It's the same problem as the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Arrays.hashCode(double[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(double%5B%5D)) is specified to return the equivalent value of a `List` containing `Double` values representing the same numeric value.

[`List.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode()) in turn is specified with a fairly simple algorithm:

```
int hashCode = 1;
for (E e : list)
    hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

In general the multiplication with a prime number is a good practice for general-purpose hash functions, but it's far from a cryptographically strong hash function.

This means that while collisions are unlikely in the general (effectively random) case, they *can* usually be constructed quite easily if you can influence (or select) the `hashCode` of the items in the List.

As a constructed example consider these two statements:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(new double[] {4.753E-321d}));
System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(new double[] {4.9E-324d, 4.9E-324d}));
```

Both of these will output 993, despite being clearly different arrays.

Comment: But collisions aren't that uncommon. Consider that the probability of hash collision in a collection of objects approaches 50% with only about 75,000 objects. And is a near certainty at 300,000 objects.

Comment: @JimMischel, but calculate that in "collisions per comparison" and you'll see how exceedingly rare they are (in non-constructed cases). They aren't inexistent by any case and the code definitely must handle them, because they *will* happen regularly.